# How to partial disabling 'Open to Explorer' Ribbon Action

Tags: 2010, permissions, ribbon, xml

I'm disabling, for all user [Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx), the 'Open with Explorer' button in the SPRibbon with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
       <CustomAction
         Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
         Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
              <CommandUIExtension>
                     <CommandUIDefinitions>
                           <CommandUIDefinition
                             Location="Ribbon.Library.Actions.OpenWithExplorer" />
                     </CommandUIDefinitions>
              </CommandUIExtension>
       </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

[reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tejasr/archive/2010/07/20/how-to-remove-open-with-windows-explorer-button-from-document-library-s-ribbon-menu.aspx)

I intend to display only for user with 'ManageWeb' Rights, however the Rights attribute works in the opposite way(Removes ribbon to every SPBasePermissions set). Any idea how to make this work?

---

update

I try to remove, with the above code, and add a new custom action of the same button with the intended Rights, but it display to all user Rights anyway:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction Id="AddExplorerButton"
            Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
            Rights="ManageWeb"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Library.Actions.OpenWithExplorer">
                    <Button Id="AddOpenWithExplorer"
                            Sequence="50"
                            Command="OpenWithExplorer"
                            Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png"
                            Image16by16Top="-112"
                            Image16by16Left="-176"
                            Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png"
                            Image32by32Top="-64"
                            Image32by32Left="-352"
                            LabelText="$Resources:core,cui_ButOpenWithExplorer;"
                            ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,cui_ButOpenWithExplorer;"
                            ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButOpenWithExplorer;"
                            TemplateAlias="o2" />
                </CommandUIDefinition>
            </CommandUIDefinitions>
        </CommandUIExtension>
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

---

update 2 - solution:

In a custom ControlTemplate called in the .master:

```
    SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPRibbon spRibbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(Page);
    if (!currentWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ManageWeb))
        spRibbon.TrimById("Ribbon.Library.Actions.OpenWithExplorer");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is afaik the only way to do it SECURELY the ajax answer on that page is a bad example however of how to acheive this, the accepted answer is the correct way:

[Hiding buttons of the Ribbon Bar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26861/hiding-buttons-of-the-ribbon-bar)