# How to remove part of a ribbon?

Tags: ribbon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hiding buttons of the Ribbon Bar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26861/hiding-buttons-of-the-ribbon-bar)

I have a list where users have contribute access - I need to remove the List Tools group in the Ribbon but still keep the Site Actions and Browse tabs. I used the below code but that removes the whole ribbon. Can anyone tell me how to specify which parts to remove?
Thank you

```
<style type="text/css">
    #s4-ribbonrow, .ms-cui-topBar2, .s4-notdlg, .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, .s4-notdlg noindex,
    #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, #s4-titlerow, #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle,
    #s4-leftpanel-content 
    {
        display:none !important;
    }

    .s4-ca
    {
        margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Cindy, Welcome to StackExchange. This question has already been asked multiple times. Example: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26861/hiding-buttons-of-the-ribbon-bar , Please refer to the [FAQ][1] on how to use this Q&A centre. [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: thanks for this - to be honest, I'm a SharePoint Novice and I don't really understand the answers to the previously posted questions.

Comment: The linked question may offer a codebehind solution to the problem, based on your actual needs. Can we ask you **why and for which users** you need to hide the two tabs? A simple solution would involve an empty custom action, but then ALL users won't view the tab anymore. Even admins...