# Removing Sharepoint Ribbon Tab based on permissions

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am currently using the method stated in the [MSDN Walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408060%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to remove the "Library" tab from the Library Tools contextual tab group and it is working for the site for all users.

However, I would like such solution conditionally to be applicable only to non-administrators. I have tried adding "Rights" element in the xml but it is not working as intended.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use other OM methods to determine the user's permission and call the TrimById method accordingly. For example, you could use DoesUserHavePermissions on the page's list item:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurableobject.doesuserhavepermissions.aspx

Please look into following link

[Hiding buttons of the Ribbon Bar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26861/hiding-buttons-of-the-ribbon-bar)